# Change number of frames allowed for each animation?

Tags: animation

I have a shoot animation which contains 15 Keyframes, and a reload that contains 70 keyframes. When I set the keyframe amount to 70 and go to the shoot animation, then change the number of keyframes to 15, only 15 keyframes show up when I go back into the reload animation.

[image: Shoot with only 15 key frames , but showing 70 frames allowed.]

[image: Reload with 70 Keyframes.]

Answer (score 5):

The frame range set on Timeline is for global output range by default. However, if you want to have a alternative preview for certain duration, you may consider to click the **Use Preview Range** button on the Timeline header.

[image]

When enabling it, you can set an alternative preview range by setting Start / End value on the header, instead of changing the global output range.

[image]

Comment: Oh sorry for wasting your time :( , but i figured out the animation stops at the last frame in different programs . Very sorry for wasting our time

Comment: @Knuckles209cp If this is the answer to your question, please consider accepting it :)

Comment: The answer was useful for me, so not a waste of time at all! ;-)

Comment: It is Useful. An ideal solution for this would if each action could have it's own start and end for easier loop previewing between actions but i don't think this is possible is it?